# docx4j template generation :can not take the placeholder containing string as a separate entity

Tags: java, jaxb, docx4j

i implemented doc generation from doc template using docx4j. template having placeholders, in my code, there replace, the place holder by a value.The problem is that docx4j can't take the placeholder as a separate entity.
   For example: template is 'tempnew.docx'

```
         welcome to <<name>>,Have a nice day in <<name>>

after running the script, i got the retrieved texts "welcome ", "to", " <<", "name>>" etc.. (check the values of 'content' each time inside the for loop in method 'replaceParagraph' of line     'Text content = (Text) t;')

instead of "welcome ", "to ", "<<name>>" etc..
```

my code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Docx4JException {
       GenerateDoc genDoc = new GenerateDoc();
    String templateFile = "C:\\testdoc\\tempnew.docx";
    WordprocessingMLPackage object = genDoc.getTemplate(templateFile);

    String toAdd = "India";
    genDoc.replaceParagraph( toAdd, object, object.getMainDocumentPart());
    genDoc.writeDocxToStream(object, "C:\\testdoc\\docgen.docx");
}


   private static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
        result.add(obj);
    else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
        for (Object child : children) {
            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }

    }
    return result;
}

      private void replaceParagraph( String textToAdd, WordprocessingMLPackage template, ContentAccessor addTo) {

    // 1. get the paragraph
     String pholderStart ="<<";
     String pholderEnd =">>";
     int placeHolderStartIndex, placeHolderEndIndex;

    List<Object> paragraphs = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), P.class);

    P toReplace = null;
    for (Object p : paragraphs) {
    List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(p, Text.class);
    for (Object t : texts) {
    Text content = (Text) t;
    ...
           ..........}..}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I'd guess that in your docx, "<<" and ">>" are split in to separate runs.

See [VariablePrepare](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/migration/VariablePrepare.java) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do not Reinvent the wheel :

```
 String inputfilepath = "C:\\template2.docx";
 String outputfilepath = "OUT_VariableReplace.docx";
 WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                    .load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
 MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
 HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
 mappings.put("name", "Hamza Guen");
 documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);
 SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
 saver.save(outputfilepath);
```

And in your template you can use ${name} as a placeholder. You can check the `VariableReplace` Documentation for more Information.